# Не работает ScrollView с Label

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Есть ContentPage, где отображается контейнер Grid, в котором есть ScrollView, хранящий в себе Label с большими текстами. Вот код:

```
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                   Text="{Binding CurrentPost.Title}" 
                   FontFamily="Montserrat-Bold" 
                   FontSize="24"
                   Margin="10, 10, 10, 0" 
                   TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray-Black}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" 
                   Text="{Binding CurrentPost.DataCategoryPostInfo}" 
                   FontFamily="Montserrat-Medium" 
                   FontSize="18" 
                   Margin="10, 0, 10, 5" 
                   TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray-800}"/>
            <BoxView Grid.Row="2" 
                     WidthRequest="{Binding LineWidth}" 
                     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                     BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Gray-400}" />
            <ScrollView Grid.Row="3" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="{Binding CurrentPost.Content}" 
                       FontFamily="Montserrat-Regular" 
                       FontSize="16" 
                       Margin="10, 0, 10, 10" 
                       TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray-Black}"/>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

Но при запуске страницы, когда текст выходит за границы экрана, не работает прокрутка. Как-будто её и нет. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: `VerticalOptions="Fill"` не сработало?

Comment: @aepot, если Вы имеете ввиду, что это нужно применить к ScrollView, то не помогло.

Comment: Нет, не это имею в виду.

Comment: @aepot, а что же?

Comment: `StackLayout` еще

Comment: @aepot, не помогло.